# Laravel projet from git inside docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to create a docker compose and docker file for my laravel project. The closes one I get is

> Could not open input file: artisan

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  webserver:
    hostname: webserver
    container_name: webserver
    image: php:8
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./webserver
    volumes:
      - /home/dockerized/laravel-exp/:/app
    ports:
      - 21280:8000
    networks:
      - dev_networks
    depends_on:
      - phpmyadmin

  db:
    #other service base in mariadb.

  phpmyadmin:
    #could use adminer.

networks:
  dev_networks:
    name: dev_networks
```

With dockerfile as such:

```
FROM php:8
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git apt-utils libonig-dev
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN rm -rf /app/*
RUN git clone https://github.com/.../myFproject.git /app && chmod +x /app/artisan

WORKDIR /app
RUN composer install

WORKDIR /app
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

I've using bitnami image but still no avail.

Comment: If this image is just for development, I would recommend to not run `RUN composer install`, as if you have any sort of issues with either `composer` or PHP or anything similar when installing, you will not be able to finish building the image, hence you will not be able to have an environment... I always recommend to build the normal image, and then you manually run any command you need that is not required to build the image to run PHP + Laravel. I do see you are using `artisan serve`. I would also recommend to install NGINX and use that other container to serve the app as it runs better

Comment: @matiaslauriti so what you meant is by using other image i.e. nginx? installing php and do laravel sail there?

Comment: No, if it is for development you should have either Sail or your own docker-compose. What I have for my dev environment is a PHP image (Dockerfile installing PHP, extensions, composer, xdebug and NPM) and then a database container and a web server (NGINX) container